# Jupyter notebook does't start, an assistance is required

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I have installed python 3.8.10, 64bit, OS Windows10, and jupyter notebook (details on jupyter are given below). Python works fine but notebook doesn't start at all. The earlier version of python as well as that of jupyter notebook worked fine.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find an answer or a solution to my problem in the internet. And I think I have tried almost everything including the cleaning of registers. Nothing works. Frankly, it would be easier, if there was any error in the command prompt, but alas nothing, just the starting process is in the kind of limbo. However, it might be related to IPython that for some reason is in the starting limbo too like notebook is, when I try to start it separately.

Info:

```
C:\Users\username>python --version
Python 3.8.10

C:\Users\username>pip show notebook
Name: notebook
Version: 6.4.5
Summary: A web-based notebook environment for interactive computing
Home-page: http://jupyter.org
Author: Jupyter Development Team
Author-email: jupyter@googlegroups.com
License: BSD
Location: c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages
Requires: argon2-cffi, ipykernel, ipython-genutils, jinja2, jupyter-client, jupyter-core, nbconvert, nbformat, prometheus-client, pyzmq, Send2Trash, terminado, tornado, traitlets
Required-by:

C:\Users\username>jupyter --version
Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 7.28.0
ipykernel        : 6.4.2
ipywidgets       : not installed
jupyter_client   : 7.0.6
jupyter_core     : 4.8.1
jupyter_server   : not installed
jupyterlab       : not installed
nbclient         : 0.5.4
nbconvert        : 6.2.0
nbformat         : 5.1.3
notebook         : 6.4.5
qtconsole        : not installed
traitlets        : 5.1.0
```

Additionally, I even installed all the uninstalled modules, it didn't worked either.

Comment: The question's text isn't formatted properly, and it also contains personal sensitive datas of the user.

Comment: what command do you run and what's the output?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend installing Anaconda. It contains Spyder (a Python IDE), Jupyter Notebook and JupyterLab (I prefer JupyterLab way better) and many more things. There's no need for for installing additional packages/updates etc. since it's all through the Anaconda navigator.

Every file is also saved.

Take a look:
https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual

Comment: Thanks a lot for a suggestion. I have found a solution. My antivirus program blocked the start of Ipython and jupyter notebook. Only after disabling it completely before installing python and other packages was I able to start everything without any problem.